# How can I rollback my recent bundle update without rolling back all my changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bundler, gemfile

I have my rails project I'm working on a separate branch.  I have made a lot of changes to things like adding new models, schema changes, etc. but I recently did a `bundle update` instead of a `bundle install` to add a new gem.  I also hadn't locked down my gem versions (which I should probably do) and it updated many to the latest versions.  This ended up breaking a lot of things it seems.  How can I roll these back without having to lose all my "other" changes in my branch?

My initial thought was to go look up all the version numbers from my `master` branches gem lock file and then add those to my existing gemfile in the branch and redo the update to roll them back.  But perhaps this isn't what I should be doing? Thanks!

Comment: If the gem update is isolated to a single commit you can use [cherry picking](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to get around the bad commit. Otherwise you should add the version constraints to gemfile and run `gem update` again to get the correct dependencies.

Comment: @max, ok thanks. I think I will go ahead and do the version numbers from looking at the `master` branches gem lock file and editing my existing gem file.  Seems I should've done that in the past anyways.

Comment: If you simply grabbed the `Gemfile.lock` form `master` and did `bundle install`, wouldn't it help? I don't think you need to constrain the versions in your `Gemfile` just to roll things back to previous state.

Comment: @BoraMa, oh, well that's a good idea I'll try that thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, use `gitk` or similar to find the last commit that had the "good" versions of your `Gemfile.lock`.

Then,  `git checkout $COMMIT Gemfile.lock` will reset that file to the version from commit `$COMMIT`. Of course,  repeat for `Gemfile` if you hacked around in that one as well.

As an aside, you generally do *not* manually lock versions of your gems in `Gemfile`, that is what `Gemfile.lock` is for.